# Understanding Grassmann's Approach to Algebras over Vector Spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

According to [Hermann Grassmann and the creation of linear algebra](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egmelvin/math54f12/math110su12_grassmann_linalg.pdf) by Desmond Sander, Grassmann was able to identify all the important notions in linear algebra in his book "Ausdehnungslehre". For him, vector spaces are freely generated by "units" $e_1, e_2, \cdots$ over real or complex numbers.

Then he embarked on studying something he called "linear products" by setting $$\left(\sum\alpha_ie_i\right)\left(\sum\beta_ie_j\right)=\sum(\alpha_i\beta_j)e_ie_j$$ subject to the condition $\color{red}{\sum\xi_{ij}e_ie_j=0.}$ According to the paper, to be invariant under change of bases, only possibilities are $$\color{blue}{e_ie_j=0,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,  e_ie_j=e_je_i,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,  e_ie_j=-e_je_i.}$$

1. What are his motivations for the relation "$\sum\xi_{ij}e_ie_j=0$"?
2. What was his derivation for those commutative relations?

Since I donot read German, I wasn't able to his original book nor I would be able to understand what he has written there.

Comment: Please confirm that the publication you are interested in is reference [11] in Sander's papers (it appears in the section **4. Products**). If so, the publication is in French, not German: Hermann Grassmann, "Sur les différents genres de multiplication." *Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik*, Vol. 49, No. 2, 1855, pp. 123-141 ([scan](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0049?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B127%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D))

Comment: Grassman does not use the same representation used by Sander. The closest I can spot is at the bottom of p. 128: $S(a_{r,s} u_{r}u_{s}) = 0$.

Comment: Understanding Grassmann's train of thought will require working through about five pages of French text, way too much for my very limited French language skills. From perusing bits and pieces, $S(a_{r,s} u_r us_s) = 0$ *seems* to be just a convenient canonical representation, as he notes notes earlier that a linear combination (my terminology, not his) $A= \beta B + \gamma C + \ldots$ can be "canonicalized" to $\alpha A + \beta B + \gamma C + \ldots = 0$. Hopefully someone fluent in French can help us out; I have not been able to locate an English translation of this publication.